# Ordering SQL results by attributes in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table of Buses that has many Stops, and each Stop record has an arrival time, how do I retrieve and order Buses by the earliest Stop time?

```
 _______    ________
| Buses |  | Stops  |
|-------|  |--------|
| id    |  | id     |
| name  |  | bus_id |
 -------   | time   |
            --------
```

I'm able to do it with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub.id, sub.name
FROM
(SELECT buses.*, stops.time
 FROM buses
 INNER JOIN stops ON stops.bus_id = buses.id
 ORDER BY stops.time) AS sub;
```

...but this has the downsides of having to do 2 queries and having to specify all the fields from buses in the SELECT DISTINCT clause. That gets particularly annoying if the buses table ever changes.

What I want to do is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT buses.*
FROM buses
INNER JOIN stops ON stops.bus_id = buses.id
ORDER BY stops.time;
```

...however in order to get `DISTINCT buses.*`, I have to include `stops.time` there as well, which gives me duplicate buses with different stop times.

What would be a better way to do this query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing you can do is to put the inner query into `ORDER BY`. This will keep the outer query "clean" as it will only select from buses. This way you won't need to return any additional fields.

```
SELECT buses.*
FROM buses
ORDER BY (
  SELECT MIN(stops.time) FROM stops WHERE stops.bus_id = buses.id
)
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer and probably best from a maintenance standpoint. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

specifying fields in select is best practice so i'm not sure why that is listed as downside.

I would do

```
Select buses.* From buses inner join
(Select stops.bus_id, min(stops.time) as mintime 
    From Stops 
    Group By stops.bus_id) st on buses.id = st.bus_id
```

or

```
Select buses.*, min(stops.time) as stoptime 
    From buses inner join stops on 
    buses.ID = stops.bus_ID group by buses.id, buses.name
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have postgresql but I assume that the problem in this question is general for any SQL
the problem is DISTINCT will *never* give correct solution because all the stop time from table **Stops** will be listed.

To get the right solution we can use GROUP BY and MIN instead..

```
SELECT B.id, B.name, MIN(S.time) MinTime
FROM
Buses B INNER JOIN Stops S
ON B.id = S.bus_id
GROUP BY B.id, B.name
ORDER BY MIN(S.time)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to open with the statement that "select distinct" is way overused and often poorly understood. It is a very limited tool and if you have already used it and the query still doesn't do what you need the next 2 tools to reach for are **1. GROUP BY** and **2. ROW_NUMBER()**

In this example where there aren't many columns needed, so a GROUP BY will produce the wanted result very easily:

```
SELECT
      B.id
    , B.name
    , MIN(S.time) MinTime
FROM Buses B
      INNER JOIN Stops S ON B.id = S.bus_id
GROUP BY
      B.id
    , B.name
ORDER BY
      MinTime
```

- nb: this is exactly the same as an answer by Susilo except I have used
  the column alias MinTIme in the order by clause

An effective alternative for this, **which is useful when you need all columns from a certain row**, such as a row that represents "*the earliest Stop time*" is to use ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT
      id
    , name
    , time
FROM (
      SELECT
            B.id
          , B.name
          , S.time
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.id ORDER BY S.time ASC) AS rowno
      FROM Buses B
            INNER JOIN Stops S ON B.id = S.bus_id
      ) dt
WHERE rowno = 1
ORDER BY
      Time
;
```

- tip: If you see/hear "earliest" or "latest" in a query requirement
  then this technique very often applies.